# Expected Exception not throwing in Visual Studio, Linq Select statement filtering results unexpectedly

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq-to-entities, linqpad

I ran into a very strange situation where a piece of code using C# and Linq to Entity that I would have expected to throw an exception but did not in Visual Studio but did in Linqpad, and I am wondering if anyone is able to explain why that is. Below are the code snippets and situations tested.

Here was the offending block of code, pulling the information of the user who modified a template:

```
Db.CommunicationTemplates.Select(i => new CommunicationTemplateModel
{
     ModificationUserId = (int)i.ModificationUserId,
     ModificationFirstName = i.ModificationUser.FirstName,
     ModificationLastName = i.ModificationUser.LastName
})
```

One of my coworkers submitted this change for testing. My developer incorrectly set the database column as nullable when it should not be:

```
public int? ModificationUserId { get; set; }
```

The test data in this case is very simple, we have 3 records. 2 have a null ModificationUserId, one has a value, such as

null
123456
null

This is a foreign key to a users table which has the First and Last Name.

I had expected this block of code to throw a casting exception, but it simply filtered out the offending and returned successfully only the one row containing "123456". In order to test the code I popped the query into Linqpad and ran it, and when doing so I did get the expected error:

```
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type
```

So that led me to as, why would this be thrown in Linqpad but not Visual Studio?

In our Visual Studio Code, I simplified the line to simply:

```
Db.CommunicationTemplates.Select(i => (int)i.ModificationUserId)
```

And to my surprise it did throw the type cast error error in both Linqpad and Visual Studio. Following this, I went back and tried the following code:

```
CommunicationTemplates.Select(i => new 
{
    ModificationFirstName = i.ModificationUser.FirstName,
    ModificationLastName = i.ModificationUser.LastName
})
```

and once again to my surprise it was returning inconsistent results. In Visual Studio, this was returning successfully only the "123456" record, and in LinqPad it was returning all 3 records. I would always expect a Select statement to throw an error before filtering results, as a select statement really should not be filtering things.

So my questions are:

- Why does Visual Studio throw a type error when only ModificationUserId is returned but suppress the error when more properties are added? Is it possibly because the name properties have already filtered this out?
- Why does accessing the name properties on the linked table return 1 result in Visual Studio but 3 in Linqpad?
- In the original combined example, does Linqpad throwing a type error but Visual Studio filtering suggest a different execution order between the applications?

I fully realize that this code can be improved and have already done so, I am simply looking for an explanation as to why the examples above execute differently than expected.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same behavior in LINQPad and Visual Studio, you must use the same API.

When you click 'Add connection' in LINQPad, you get to choose the API: LINQ-to-SQL or Entity Framework (EF Core in LINQPad 6). If you choose LINQ-to-SQL, you must use also use LINQ-to-SQL in Visual Studio if you want the same behavior. And if you choose EF or EF Core, make sure that the version you choose matches what you're using in Visual Studio.